# More pythonic way to write this function

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x

I wonder if there any more pythonic way to write this function:

```
def parse(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='koi8-r') as f:
        for log_line in f:
            for s in services:
                if ' ' + s + ' ' in log_line:
                    print(s)
                    services.remove(s)
```

Comment: Your code is almost certainly broken. Don't remove while iterating.

Comment: As Mark said, don't remove while iterating -- and my question, on top of that, is why are you removing things from this global services list in a function named `parse`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He is iterating over the services here: `for s in services:`

Comment: Use sets instead of lists and just use the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sets:

```
def parse(filename):
    servicesset = set(services)
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='koi8-r') as f:
        for log_line in f:
            words = set(log_line.split())
            servicesset -= words

    services[:] = list(servicesset)
```

This presumes the `services` global is a list. Note that it'd be *much* better to pass *in* services then return the result:

```
def parse(filename, services):
    services = set(services)
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='koi8-r') as f:
        for log_line in f:
            words = set(log_line.split())
            services -= words

    return list(servicesset)
```

Comment: I think that using discard here is not an option, because logline should _contain_ service. They are not exactly equal

Comment: @kernel_mode: does anything in `services` contain spaces?

Comment: @kernel_mode: I've now split lines into words and removed any that are in services, but that only works if nothing in `services` contain spaces.